# Why does a mysql Insert query fail *only* when the table is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am running these two statements one right after another in some PHP code.

```
INSERT INTO input (ID) VALUES('1');
UPDATE input SET `vendor_name` = 'some name' WHERE ID=1
```

If the database table is empty (meaning I just truncated the table), **no** data is created, no warnings appear.  It's as if I never executed the query.

If I then run **just**

```
   INSERT INTO input (ID) VALUES('1');
```

On this *exact same* clear table, an entry is created no problem.
After that, if I again run the *same* INSERT/UPDATE querys

```
INSERT INTO input (ID) VALUES('2');
UPDATE input SET `vendor_name` = 'some name' WHERE ID=2
```

Then the data is created and the vendor_name set appropriately.  What is going on here??  I seem to be misunderstanding something fundamental about inserting data into a database.  Can I not execute statements back-to-back like this on an empty table?

To pre-empt the inevitable silly questions like 'does the column exist?', here is some extra notes:

- NO warnings ever appear.  This really bugs me.  The INSERT/UPDATE seems to fail silently.  (yes, yes, I have set error reporting on and I checked the logs)
- The appropriate columns/tables/databases/permissions exist and are defined (remember the query works fine if there is an empty row in the table)
- ID is the primary key.  The numbers I used  for IDs (1,2, whatever) do not seem to matter.  I could just as well reverse them, or use 101 and 102, whatever.
- Create table looks like so: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY).  Columns are added dynamically by users.  So right now there's about 100 columns in the table ( keep in mind this shouldn't matter.  I'm only trying to update *one* column, and that update works fine if there is data in the table)
- Sneaking a Count(*) query in there reveals that the row *is* created, but then disappears after the Update statement.  (Perhaps the row wasn't completed, or something, and there's a 'make sure the insert is finished' query I need to run?)

Comment: drop/create table again gives same result? Please use 1 instead of '1' when you do the insert, if the column is numeric (not the problem I know)

Comment: One comment: take away the quotes around `1` if the column type of `ID` is INT.

Comment: It is an Int type, but why does that matter - remember, the query, quotes and all, works just fine if data exists in the table.

Comment: please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: Considering ID is auto_increment, why do you insert a value into it? Just for testing purposes? Can it have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Syntax matters. Telling someone that your poor syntax works 'sometimes' introduces an unneeded variable to people trying to solve your problem. Why not fix the syntax, double-check it to make sure it didn't magically fix your problem, and then update the question with the proper syntax? It will save everyone time! Also you should not be inserting id's into an auto-id field.

Comment: Why do you say syntax is the problem?  The problem is the same with or without quotes.  The reason I insert an ID into an auto-id field is because users have the ability to add rows, and I need to keep track of which rows which users added, so they can edit their data and only their data.  Hence I record the ID they inserted.

Comment: @user396483 Ever heard of [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html) resp. [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.... for me its works....

```
INSERT INTO `input` (ID) VALUES('1');
UPDATE `input` SET `vendor_name` = 'some name' WHERE ID=1
```